# How to change border colour run-time?

Tags: java, swing, colors, border, jscrollpane

I'm trying to change JScrollPane's border colour:

```
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane (textPane, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
Color color = new Color(150, 255, 243);
scroll.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(new EmptyBorder(3, 3, 4, 4), new LineBorder(color, 7)));

//some other code

//if smth happens then:

color = Color.red;
```

but my "scroll" is always the same.. how can I see border color changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the color variable does not actually change the border. You'd have to set the border again, not just change the color variable.

Think about a simpler example, a JLabel that contains some text.

```
String text = "example";
JLabel label = new JLabel(text);
text = "changed";
```

The JLabel would still show "example" even though the variable has changed.

You would still have to set the text of the JLabel again:

```
String text = "example";
JLabel label = new JLabel(text);
text = "changed";
label.setText(text);
```

Similarly, you have to set the border again.

Comment: Right, and his question is why the border doesn't automagically change when he changes the color variable later in the code.

Comment: i thought there were a trick to maintain the compound border i created, not to create a new border every time I want to change its colour, but this work! ty

Comment: @Dario you could maintain a reference to your LineBorder (which is the border with the color), but it doesn't have a setColor() method. You might be able to hack something together by subclassing LineBorder and keeping track of the color yourself, but just setting the border again is probably the way to go.

Comment: @Dario: If Kevin's answer solved your problem (which it should), then please accept it, and then later up-vote it.

Answer (score 6):

There is a simpler way to override the paintBorder() method in the example by Java42 because the lineColor field is protected. So simply do:

```
@Override
public void paintBorder(final Component c, final Graphics g, final int x, final int y, final int width, final int height) {
    super.lineColor = color;
    super.paintBorder(c, g, x, y, width, height);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

To dynamically change a LineBorder(), you have to override its paintBorder() method.

Here is the important snippet:

```
    lineBorder = new LineBorder(color, 7) {
        @Override
        public void paintBorder(final Component c, final Graphics g, final int x, final int y, final int width, final int height) {
            // super.paintBorder(c, g, x, y, width, height);
            final boolean doSimple = true;
            if (doSimple) {
                g.setColor(color);
                g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
            }
       }
  };
```

Here is an instructional example:

```
public class LineBorder_ColorChange {

static JTextPane  textPane    = new JTextPane();
static JScrollPane scrollPane;
static Color      color       = new Color(150, 255, 243);
static Border     emptyBorder = new EmptyBorder(3, 3, 4, 4);
static Border     lineBorder;
static Border     border;
static JButton    jButton     = new JButton("Change Color");
static Random     random      = new Random();

public static void main(final String[] args) {

    final JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();

    lineBorder = new LineBorder(color, 7) {
        @Override
        public void paintBorder(final Component c, final Graphics g, final int x, final int y, final int width, final int height) {
            // super.paintBorder(c, g, x, y, width, height);
            final boolean doSimple = false;
            if (doSimple) {
                g.setColor(color);
                g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
            }
            else {
                if ((this.thickness > 0) && (g instanceof Graphics2D)) {
                    final Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
                    final Color oldColor = g2d.getColor();
                    g2d.setColor(color);
                    Shape outer;
                    Shape inner;
                    final int offs = this.thickness;
                    final int size = offs + offs;
                    if (this.roundedCorners) {
                        final int arc = offs + size;
                        outer = new RoundRectangle2D.Float(x, y, width, height, arc, arc);
                        inner = new RoundRectangle2D.Float(x + offs, y + offs, width - size, height - size, arc, arc);
                    }
                    else {
                        outer = new Rectangle2D.Float(x, y, width, height);
                        inner = new Rectangle2D.Float(x + offs, y + offs, width - size, height - size);
                    }
                    final Path2D path = new Path2D.Float(Path2D.WIND_EVEN_ODD);
                    path.append(outer, false);
                    path.append(inner, false);
                    g2d.fill(path);
                    g2d.setColor(oldColor);
                }
            }
        }
    };

    border = new CompoundBorder(emptyBorder, lineBorder);

    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textPane);

    jButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
            color = new Color(random.nextInt(142), random.nextInt(142), random.nextInt(142));
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
            jFrame.repaint();
        }
    });

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            scrollPane.setBorder(border);
            jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            jFrame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            jFrame.getContentPane().add(jButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            jFrame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            jFrame.setSize(200, 200);
            jFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            jFrame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just started learning Java and ran into this same issue of updating the border color. 
If you're only going to use a few colors, there is an alternative to overriding the paint method, and that is to create a separate border object for each color.

In my case, I wanted a border that matched the background color (appearing transparent), and a black border when the component is selected, toggling the border color each time the label is selected. The code below is incomplete, but I hope it gives sufficient information.

```
public class YourClass { 
    final private static java.awt.Color TRANSPARENT_BORDER = new java.awt.Color(190,190,225); 
    final private static java.awt.Color VISIBLE_BORDER     = new java.awt.Color(  0,  0,  0); 
    final private LineBorder transparentBorder = new LineBorder( TRANSPARENT_BORDER, 1); 
    final private LineBorder visibleBorder     = new LineBorder( VISIBLE_BORDER,     1); 

    public YourClass() 
    { 
        yourLabel = new JLabel(); 
        yourLabel.setBorder( transparentBorder ); 

        yourLabel.addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter()  
        { 
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked( MouseEvent e )  
            { 
                if ( borderColor == TRANSPARENT_BORDER ) { 
                    yourLabel.setBorder(  visibleBorder );
                    borderColor = VISIBLE_BORDER; 
                } else {
                    yourLabel.setBorder( transparentBorder ); 
                    borderColor   = TRANSPARENT_BORDER; 
                } 
            } 
        });
```